# Customizable setUp for every test in a test class

Tags: python, unit-testing

Is it possible for to configure the setUp method to use different parameters depending on which test I am running? 
In the setUp method I have a class that I want to instantiate with different parameters, depending which test I am running. I understand that typically this is what the test method is for, but I need that class instantiated before I setUp anything else.

A solution that I have is to create another method that does everything I want setUp to do and then call it in every test, but I was wondering if the built in setUp method is able to do that?

I know that the example below does not work, as setUp does not take any args, but I was looking for something along these lines.

Also, what would be a better alternative to this?

Example:

```
class TestComponents(unittest.TestCase):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.app = MyApplication()
        unittest.TestCase.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def setUp(component):
        self.app.start([component])

    def testComponent1():
        # test continues here

    def testComponent2():
        # test continues here
```

Comment: Could you have a method like `mySetUp(self, **attrs)` and manually call it from within your tests?

Comment: If setUps are not common at all, initialization should be done in test method. If some of set-ups are common, they should be put in separate test suites. Anyway, I guess we try to solve an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here. Could you show us some code to give us better insight on what exactly you try to accomplish here?

Comment: Yes, this is what I was thinking to do, but I was looking for a more elegant solution. It sounds like something a tester might want to do more often, and thought that there might be an out-of-the box solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a base class for your tests. The `setUp` method can reference a class attribute that will contain the parameter you want to vary.

```
class TestBase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # do something with self.MYPARAMETER
```

then divide your tests among a set of subclasses, each of which defines `MYPARAMETER` differently. You may or may not need to define `setUp` locally, depending on whether the code itself needs to be extended beyond
what you can put in `TestBase.setUp`.

```
class Test1(TestBase):
    MYPARAMETER = 1
    def setUp(self):
        TestBase.setUp(self)
        # etc

class Test2(TestBase):
    MYPARAMETER = 17
    def setUp(self):
        TestBase.setUp(self)
        # etc
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a great alternative.

Comment: Your approach of overriding `__init__` might be useful as well, but would probably require writing a custom test runner. I've never really looked into how test classes are ultimately instantiated.